# How to Insert Link to Mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I need help please, I'm having problem inserting a link into my `Mysql` Database using PHP like this:
Example:  http://www.textlinkgravity.com/link.php?id=8781&title=Deerpages.co-Free-Online-Business-Directory.html

In `Mysql` Database upon insert would be:
http://www.textlinkgravity.com/link.php?id=8781

My problem is that the & symbol is being cut. I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Here is my code:

```
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);   
//INSERT NEW ROW
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (link) VALUES ('$link') ");
```

My apology for my question cause I don't know how to insert it having complete strings as of this moment.

Thanks to all.

Comment: it works fine for me, and i see "http://www.textlinkgravity.com/link.php?id=8781&title=Deerpages.co-Free-Online-Business-Directory.html" after using mysql_real_escape_string.. have you checked the length of your varchar field?

Comment: my length is 685 varchar. I'm bit confused now.

Comment: weird indeed, have you tried echoing out the $link before running the query?

Comment: yeah it's bit weird. yeah, I'm echoing it and seems okay and complete strings but when you trigger to insert it then it cuts.

Answer (score 4):

You should [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your URL before inserting

```
$link = mysql_real_escape_string( urlencode($_POST['link']) );
```

Comment: Hi, after using your suggestion, now after inserting the new row it will look like this. http%3A%2F%2Fwww.textlinkgravity.com%2Flink.php%3Fid%3D8781

Comment: That's how it should look. When you're fetching it from DB and displaying you have to decode it again - [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: now I've tried to urldecode it but it cuts again. Same result as normal insertion. What to do. I've just discovered the problem.

Comment: it works - http://codepad.viper-7.com/ISSh63 you might want to look into `mysql_real_escape_string` caused changes or switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: hi thanks for the effort of solving problem, I've just tested your code and it works fine. But, have you tried inserting to mysql database? Please let me know if it's working fine. Thanks.